# Buy bus ticket on line for use between Paraguay and Argentina

Tags: buses, argentina, south-america, paraguay, asuncion

I want to book a bus ticket on line from Asuncion Paraguay to Resistencia Argentina - is there a web site with English to do so

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.  If you use the multipurpose RometoRio site to search for [routes between those two cities](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Asunci%C3%B3n/Resistencia), you can see that there's a bus that takes 3 hours, with a link to [sol del paraguay to buy it](http://www.soldelparaguay.com.py/horarios.php).

However, it is in Spanish.  If you have Google Chrome, however, there's usually a popup 'translate this page' option which will try and convert it into English onthe fly for you.  If not, give it a try - there's not that many boxes and it's reasonably clear often what it is.

Some hints: Origen = Origin, Destino = destination, Ida = date, Regreso = return. Busar = search.  If you get stuck, you can use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) to help too!